# Solving the given separable initial value problem.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -3y; \quad (2,6)$$

This is what I've done so far.

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = -3y $$
$$ dy = -3y \, dx $$
$$ dx = \frac{dy}{-3y} $$
$$ dx = dy \cdot \frac{1}{3} y $$
$$ \int dx = \frac{1}{3} \int y \,dy $$
$$ x = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{y^2}{2} + c $$
$$ x = \frac{y^2}{6} + c $$

So at this point I should just plug $(2,6)$ in right? or is the whole working all messed up?

Comment: How did you get "$dy.\frac{1}{3}.y$" in the right-hand side in the fourth line? $A/B$ and $A\cdot B$ are two different things! (Not to mention the lost negative sign, which is probably just a typo.)

Comment: uh i bring the dx to the right side and bring the 3y the left side where the dy is reside. Since 3y dy make sense. Also, it turns out it wasn't a typo at all, i sincerely had forgotten it. Woops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work should look like:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-3y$$
$$\frac{dy}{y}=-3\,dx$$
Integrating both sides yeilds: $$\log y =-3x+C$$
Exponentiate both sides: $$y=Ke^{-3x}$$ where $K=e^C$

Since you are given initial condition $x=2$ and $y=6$, you can plug in those values to get:$$6=Ke^{-6}$$
 So $$K=6e^6$$
and the full equation would be $$y=6e^{-3x+6}$$